# Event passed to onkeyup and onkeydown handlers doesn't set event.key value on Chrome with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs

When i run following code in Chrome I cannot access the event.key value:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
     return { value: 'Empty' }
  },

  keyHandler: function(e){
    e.persist();
    var value = e.type + ':' + e.key;

    this.setState(function(previousState, currentProps) {
       return { value: previousState.value + '\n' + value };
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
    <div>
      <input 
        onKeyDown={this.keyHandler}
        onKeyUp={this.keyHandler}
        onKeyPress={this.keyHandler}
      />
      <pre>{this.state.value}</pre>
     </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

On latest IE and Firefox it works fine, but on chrome I got following result:
[image: Result in chrome]

As far as I understand React documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html React's events should provide cross-browser behavior so I'd expect the same result in all browsers. Did I miss something?

PS. I've created a jsfiddle to play with this issue: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/38132/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/67f8524e88abbf1ac0fd86d38a0477d11fbc7b3e/src/renderers/dom/client/utils/getEventKey.js#L35) you can see that when the *key* is not on the native event object, React only translates *keyCode* into the missing *key* for the special keys:

```
/**
 * Translation from legacy `keyCode` to HTML5 `key`
 * Only special keys supported, all others depend on keyboard layout or browser
 * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Key_names
 */
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I wrongly assumed that React is providing normalized cross-browser behavior with its SyntheticEvent. I'd suggest to use a proper polyfill to provide KeyboardEvent.key handling. http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key